# scikit-learn: Issues on RFECV example

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I'm having a difficulty in understanding the given [RFECV example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#example-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) in current documentation. In the plot it's been written as "nb of misclassifications", so i expect it to be "lower the better". But in the example plot the best has been chosen as the highest cross-validation score. So i naturally expect it to be something related to accuracy (scoring says accuracy in the code anyways). But then how it becomes higher than 1?

I am a bit confused on how to interpret these results. I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) has a useful `verbose` option. Running with `verbose=2`, you can see, that for a 2-fold cross-value check, as in example, `grid_scores_` holds sum of both folds scores.

In general, for a n-fold check, `grid_scores_` is sum of folds scores divided by `n-1`, [see in code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py#L371). It seems to be a bug;  see somewhat relevant [issue on the tracker](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2403).